# Build error when using Mac C++ to connect to sqlite3

Tags: c++, xcode, sqlite

I am attempting to learn how to connect to sqlite3 using C++ on a Mac Xcode compiler.

I have the following include files..

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"
```

I have tried the two sqlite3 open functions…

sqlite3_open and sqlite3_open_v2

The Xcode tool finds no errors until I try to compile.  Then I get a “Build Failed” error with no further explanation.

What is the likely cause and how can I track down the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely cause is your code is incorrect (eg. `#include "sqlite3.h"` should be `#include <sqlite3.h>`, etc). Without posting the exact error nobody here can tell you specifically why.

How to track down the error is pointed out in the [documention](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-log_navigator/articles/log_navigator-about.html):

> **Choose View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator** to view the reports that
>   Xcode generates during your development process. Alternatively, you
>   can click the log navigator button 
>   in the navigator selector bar of the workspace window.

↳ [Finding and Fixing Issues from the Log Viewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-log_navigator/FindingandFixingIssuesfromtheLogViewer/FindingandFixingIssuesfromtheLogViewer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010353-CH12-SW1)

Comment: Thanks very much.  Tried that too and it did not work.  Using "..." instead of <...> broadens the search area and often works even when <...> would work.  The only error returned is the one I quoted.  Hence the problem and my question.

Comment: Xcode would not output `Build Failed` without an accompanying error message in the Log Viewer. If it's not there then maybe do a screencapture and show it in your question.

Comment: Thank you.  Well it was a round-about deal, but I found the problem.  I needed to add libsqlite3.dylib to the project "build phases" options. Now it is working. Doesn't care if the include has "..." or <...>.  Thank you for getting me to the solution.

Comment: You're welcome, `""` are used for "local" imports/includes and `<>` for "global" imports/includes; you should get in the habit of using the proper ones.  Did you find the actual error in the Log Viewer? Hopefully so, as it will help you tremendously in the future. cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that.  It was new to me. I didn't find the exact error. But I did find an error of ... "symbol not found for architecture x86_64" And that was puzzling.  However, I searched stack overflow on that string plus sqlite3 and found someone else who had the same problem.  That's how it turned out to be round-about.  Could not have done that without your help.  And I learned a lot from it.  Thank you very much.